# Changing <p> html via shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the below html and I would like to change the change the `<p> Text </p>` section based on a var in my shell script.

```
<div id="demo"><p> Text </p></div>
```

I have been attempting to use the below function, but it doesn´t seem to work, Also I need it to pick up change whatever is in the `<p> Text </p>` section as it will change regularly

```
fnChangeTxt()
{
        sed -i 's/<div id="'$1'"><p>*.*</<div id="'$1'"><p>'$2'</' /var/www/html/alarm.html
}
```

Calling the function

```
fnChangeTxt 'demo' 'Next'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your quoting. For readability, I'd suggest using a different delimiter for the `s` command - one that is less likely to appear in the text you're modifying. That will make it less likely for a reader to be confused by seeing slashes in odd places in something that's working with HTML.

```
fnChangeTxt() 
{
     sed -i "s|<div id=\"$1\"><p>.*<|<div id=\"$1\"><p>$2<|" /var/www/html/alarm.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the single quotes will prevent replacing the variables with the provided input.

Secondly you need only `.*` to match "everything". (acually "0 ro more occurences of any character")

Answer (score 0):

No need for `sed` really:

```
#!/bin/bash

new='some stuff'

while read
do
    echo ${REPLY/<p>*<\/p>/<p> $new </p>}

done << '__END__'
<div id="demo"><p> Text </p></div> 
<div id="demo"><p> Text </p></div> 
__END__
```

Gives:

```
<div id="demo"><p> some stuff </p></div>
<div id="demo"><p> some stuff </p></div>
```

Replace the here document with your filename.

Comment: Thanks, but I think sed is a little cleaner than your option

Comment: @Rhys: cleaner?  Isn't it cleaner to write everything in the same language (`bash`) rather than switching to another (`sed`)?  'Clean', like beauty, must be in the eye of the beholder.